# Nginx reverse proxy is not working for API/v2_soap

Tags: nginx

I'm having a problem with a reverse proxy at nginx...

Problem ->

I have the server A with nginx that receive many connections by port 80 and 443...
some connection come from api/rest and api/v2_soap...
for these connections i made a proxy rule to redirect to connection to server B, that will process the api request

The Rule at server A:

```
location /api/rest {
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
proxy_pass http://10.0.0.2;
proxy_redirect off;
}


location /api/v2_soap {
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
proxy_pass http://10.0.0.2;
proxy_redirect off;
}
```

Fine... When i look inside server B nginx acess.log all connections are being redirect to server B.. Great...

But when the connection is being process , the server B access log show some GET request as status 200 and some POST requests as status 500

mydomain.com.br 10.0.0.2 - - [17/Jun/2019:15:35:21 -0300] "GET /api/v2_soap?wsdl=1 HTTP/1.0" 200 244478 "-" "-" "xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx"

mydomain.com.br 10.0.0.2 - - [17/Jun/2019:15:35:25 -0300] "GET /api/v2_soap?wsdl=1 HTTP/1.0" 200 244478 "-" "-" "xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx"

mydomain.com.br 10.0.0.2 - - [17/Jun/2019:15:35:26 -0300] "POST /api/v2_soap HTTP/1.0" 500 423 "-" "Axis/1.4" "xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx"

mydomain.com.br 10.0.0.2 - - [17/Jun/2019:15:35:28 -0300] "POST /api/v2_soap HTTP/1.0" 500 423 "-" "Axis/1.4" "xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx"

The configuration at nginx server B for api are:

```
# API config
location /api/rest {
rewrite ^/api/rest /api.php?type=rest last;
}

# API config
location /api/v2_soap {
rewrite ^/api/v2_soap /api.php?type=v2_soap last;
```

Now the question... what is wrong, what i must add, what i must do to apis rest and soap work fine at my server...

the central problem i think is soap connections... because i found some rest status POST and GET with status 200

Answer (score 0):

Quite confuse on the `rewrite` rule. At server A, you have rewrite the URI `/api/rest` and `/api/v2_soap` to `$1`, which will strip those URI and left any parameters / values at the back of the URI and pass to server B, example, if you send `/api/rest/abc123` to server A, server B will receive as `/abc123`.

From the access log you shared, it looks like your application / service is responding http 200 if there is parameter `wsdl` after URI `/api/v2_soap`, otherwise it's returning http 500, which could mean your application does not recognize the request.

I would suggest to check on what request payload does your application needed then only configure

Comment: About the "rewrite ^/api/rest(/.*)$ $1 break;", i have tried to you the proxy without it, unfortunately the result was the same, make sense what you said about it, but the result it was the same result ;'/

Comment: you have replaced `/api/v2_soap` to `/api.php?type=v2_soap` at server A, so you should be configuring server B to accept `/api.php?type=v2_soap` and pass to the application.

Comment: this case rewrite ^/api/v2_soap(/.*)$ $1 break; makes no difference to my case... without the rule the result is the same...

i cant make get/post with rest...but only get with this rule... the POST result as an error

Answer (score 0):

About the v2_soap 500, maybe the awnser is here:

```
# API configuration 
location /api/v2_soap { 
rewrite ^/api/v2_soap /api.php?type=v2_soap last;
}
```

i search at internet, and nginx documentation, and i just found this rule with some variations, none worked

*fact: if i use the server A to recive and process the api/v2_soap connection, it works!! and at nginx configuration at server A its just

```
# API config location /api/rest { 
rewrite ^/api/rest /api.php?type=rest last; 
}
```

no rules for v2_soap, and its i tried use just api/rest rules at server B.